# codeigniter database calls from view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hey guys was hoping you could help me out.

basically i'm working on a website created using codeigniter by someone else. The site has two instances, one for development and one for live. The site is still under construction which means files are constantly being changed and moved from the development site (after being tested) to the live site.

Now the thing is, the person who initially created the site made some database calls from a few views. And to access the database from the view, he manually connected to the database from the view, i.e using

```
$db=mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_db(...);
```

This means that each time a view is changed, before copying the files from the dev site to the live site, we need to change the variables inside these views.

moving all queries to models, and then calling them through controllers would take too long, so was wondering if there was a way through which i could access the database variables in the database.php file and pass them as the variable for mysql_connect.

i tried $this->db->database but get the error "Undefined property: CI_Loader::$db"

thanks in advance

Comment: "moving all queries to models, and then calling them through controllers would take too long" This is where I leave the question.

Comment: Set the connection details to some constants and define them in your config file. It's not pretty, but it should work. You can then play with the if(DEV) use dev values else use live.

Comment: sounds like the person who made that didn't understand or didn't try to understand codeigniter at all.  ideally you should replace the db calls in view with data passed to those view from the controller after the controller uses a call to the db via a model or models.

Comment: Would moving all the queries to models take longer than updating them EVERY single time you want to deploy something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define constants in constant.php assign them database username , password , host name etc and use them anywhere you want

Comment: This is not correct way to call database calls from view. It will be security concern also.

Comment: autoload a model ? include all functions that you want to call from the view into the model

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access database object from view. And you should also not do

```
$db=mysql_connect(...);
mysql_select_db(...);
```

in view. Try to remove those calls from view. And call it from model.

That is what [MVC in codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html)  used for. Othervise what is use of using codeigniter framework.

See also:

1. [access model from view in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719876/access-model-from-view-in-codeigniter)
2. [CodeIgniter - Calling a function from inside a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357225/codeigniter-calling-a-function-from-inside-a-view)

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't be eager about moving database calls to views, than take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5835321/1444604

Answer (score 0):

If this site is under construction yet, it shall be much better fix all this programing issues now than later.

Remembering that mysql_* codes are deprecated and won´t go much longer be accepted by hosts.

A hint that you could use what sometimes we forget, are those options of replacing texts presents in som many text editors and IDE´s, normally with a shortcut ctrl + H, you can rewrite a lot of code in many files, but be careful, or this can get all worse.

Well... said that, what you´ve tried to do in the view $this->db->database() maybe can work if you use this code before load database. I think it should
work just like as when creating libraries.

$CI =& get_instance();

Give a look on, but even if it works, avoid it as much as you can:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Good Luck!